# RecyclerView hold first visible item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: Gif animation]

How create animation like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a library at your project and use the one you like most.

https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: I know about this lib. But no examle there.